# When using OpenCV's 2D feature detection on an image, how do I export the data as a CSV for external use?

Tags: node.js, csv, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I'm using the Node OpenCV module to process an image. I'm able to find the face and save it. I can even compare similar images.

Once I have opened a file, how do I export that data as a single row in a CSV?

The end goal is to train an Amazon Machine Learning model to recognize a certain kind of face i/e faces that are sad. Then, it will tell me how similar new faces are to also "looking sad", etc.

I'm new to CV and ML in general, any help or direction would be appreciated.

Here's pseudo-code as to what I'd like to do (or at least steps in general).

#### Training Data Creation

- For each training image - find features (ex: corners of the mouth, wrinkles, bags under eyes, etc.)
- Save each result as a row in a .CSV file
- Export that CSV to S3

...train model on Amazon...

#### Process New Files

- A new file is uploaded
- Find features (same as above)
- Save as row in CSV

...will batch process to Amazon via queue...

Answer (score 0):

CSV files once saved can be written to any file with a `.csv` extension. 
To write the data as a CSV make sure each variable or value is separated by a comma like so   `val1,val2,val3,val4` . Write to the file in this format to separate the data. You can try opening the file in MSExcell to confirm that the write was accurate. Excel should separate the data into different cells.