# How to save feature values extracted from images in csv format using python?

Tags: python, csv

I have extracted some features from images and now I want to save these values in csv file. I have searched some links like ([When using OpenCV's 2D feature detection on an image, how do I export the data as a CSV for external use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065724/when-using-opencvs-2d-feature-detection-on-an-image-how-do-i-export-the-data-a?rq=1)) and ([how to save feature matrix as csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348445/how-to-save-feature-matrix-as-csv-file)), but not getting the solution to my problem.
How to make csv of these features in python?

Comment: You don't want to "save image data in a CSV file". You want to "save data in a CSV file". The CSV format does not care one bit what kind of data it is you're saving, so you should stop looking at threads that make it more complicated than it is. Pick an example/tutorial that is about creating CSV files in Python. There are thousands upon thousands of samples on that topic, and pretty much any one of them will be good enough. Then do the same thing, but with your data.

Comment: Thanks, @Tomalak for your reply... I am able to save values in .csv file but all these values are in one column. However, I want to save these values in proper tabular form with heading and per image. How can I do this?

Comment: Your response suggests that you have not looked at enough examples/tutorials/SO questions on the topic of "CSV with Python", and you have not thoroughly compared your code to working code from an example. Writing a CSV file with Python is (*literally!*) a matter of less than 5 lines of code. Again. Pick a working example and rewrite it to use your own data.

Comment: Thanks again... I have seen many examples and implemented them. These are working well with synthetic data. But, the problem is, I want to use it inside a loop. In my case, I have a loop that reads images one by one from a folder and extracts features from these. The first image features are stored in the first iteration and then the second and so on. I am facing actually two problems. The Header values are repeated for each image which is row and extracted features are in column form. Thus, I am not getting the desired result by implementing these examples directly. Please suggest me solution

Comment: Then I think it's time that you show the code you have so far-

Comment: My problem is solved...Thanks a lot for your response